# Field Is too large (32K) or View's column & selection formulas are too large

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I receive this error on running agent :  Field Is too large (32K) or View's column & selection formulas are too large

the coding stop on

```
Call timedoc.save(true,false) line error during save
```

It dint say which "field" contain this error. My view contain 110000 document. Is that the problem of having this error?

Comment: This is common (but not very helpful) behavior, that it throws the error on save, when allocation and memcheck of your doc and fields are running. In this case you might really start debugging on your own. Start especially with plain text fields or fields with multiple values, which are often cause of the famous 32bit problem. Try to replace them with rich text fields as a shorthand solution or better, make smaller and more granular data structures.

Answer (score 2):

The max size of **all** text fields in a document which have set the *summary flag* is **32K**.
The summary flag is set by default to true and has to be set to true if you want to show a field's content in a view.

You can set an item's (field's) summary flag to false this way:

```
myItem.setSummary(false)
```

If you set field's summery flag to false then the limit is 32K for every such text field.

Comment: With Feature Pack 8 this limit was raised up to 16 MB (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKTMJ_9.0.1/admin/over_whats_new_in_fp8.html)

Comment: i found the document that contain error. i use debugging for running live times agent and it stop on that document. The document one of the field contain too much wording inside. which hit the limit of the field. ~